# Java Concurrency: should I synchronize all List and Maps?

Tags: java, concurrency

So I have a `SomeTask` class which `extends Thread`, and it has `Map` and `List` fields. What would be the behavior when you don't do `Collections.synchronizedXXX` and you have multiple thread of SomeTask running?

Once a Map is called from the database (I am using Object Database to directly store POJO), would I need to synchronized the Map object returned from this database as well?

`Map SomeTasksOwnMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(MapReturnedFromDatabase);`

Comment: but don't each thread get it's own instances of the Map?

Comment: @KimJongWoo - of course they don't.  Whatever gave you that idea?

Comment: Blind synchronization is ... blind. Don't do it. Consider thread-boundaries and how data is moved across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collections.synchronizedXXX`  is required when 2 or more Threads are accessing the same Map/List.

If your task doesn't access other tasks Map/List, then there is no need to synchronize them.

Example.

- Task 1 builds a list of numbers divisible exactly by 2.
- Task 2 builds a list of numbers divisible exactly by 3.

These two tasks have individual lists that do not require synchronization.

Example require synchronization.

- Task 1 and 2 both calculate numbers and store them in a shared list.

To answer the questions: "What would be the behavior when you don't", you could lose one of the writes if it was timed that both threads wanted to write to index 'x'.

You may also have a null value in the list as the size of the array was increased before the write to the location was done.

Basically you would have an inconsistent view.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is nothing in your question that suggests synchronization is required, because as far as I can tell each thread reads only data within itself: You only need synchronization when threads access data in other threads.

As an aside, having `SomeTask extends Thread` is a poor design - it should `extends Runnable`, then use `new Thread(new SomeTask()).start()`.

Answer (score 0):

> ... should I synchronize **all** List and Maps?

No you shouldn't.  Synchronizing things that don't need it is a waste of resources.  And for things that do need synchronization, you need to do it the right way.  (And the `synchronizedXxx` wrappers are not always the right way.)

First, you need to identify the data structures that are going to be visible to multiple threads.  Data structures that are provably thread confined don't need synchronizing at all.

Second, you need to examine the way that the data structures are used to see if a `synchronizedXxx` wrapper is sufficient.  For instance, these wrappers don't synchronize iteration, and you can get into trouble if one thread changes a collection while another one is iterating it.

Finally, you need to think about whether the synchronized data structures are heavily used by different threads.  The `synchronzedXxx` wrappers can result in a performance bottleneck if the data structure is heavily used.  If this is the case, you should consider using one of the `ConcurrentYyyy` classes instead.